# Is it possible to limit access to an svn server to not just credentials but to machines as well?

Tags: ubuntu, security, svn, access-control-list

my office has provided laptops to all staff in addition to the new desktops we just have. I have been asked to secure our `svn server` which is a dedicated server hosted somewhere with `ubuntu` running on it.

Limiting access in this case means that only senior developers can access `svn repositories` on their laptops. the rest of the developers team can only have access on the new desktops not their laptops

we currently access the repositories using `http/s:`

Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Are you using mod_dav_svn? What do you mean by - "do their svn stuff on the new desktops" ?

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: I don't understand differences between "normal activities" and activities of senior developers. Could you clarify more detailed? One of them should use some specific dav commands? For e.g. PROPFIND ...

Comment: Hello , I think you got it wrong. it's either one can use it on laptops or not. Everybody should have access and whatever on all desktops. only senior devs can access work on svn on their laptops. I edited the port to make it clearer. sorry for the confusion caused

Comment: Are the laptops in different subnet from the desktops?

Comment: No. all office IPs are of the type `192.168.0.*` and we all access the svn online via https://repo.mycompanyname/svn

Answer (score 0):

Subversion and mod_dav_svn does not allow authorize users based on computer name.

You need to split you lan

```
192.168.0.0/24 - for new desktops
192.168.1.0/24 - for laptops of senior developers
192.168.2.0/24 - other developers
```

and then you could try to use iptables with time module

```
# iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d repo.mycompanyname --dport 80 -j DROP
# iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -s 192.168.2.0/24 -d repo.mycompanyname --dport 80 -m time --timestart 09:00 --timestop 18:00 --days Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: I've never thought of it this way. nice approach. Will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Not through typical SVN capabilities, but anything is possible if you wish to do some hacking.  You will need some way to identify the computer that is trying to connect, if they are not on different subnets, then there is not much you can do.  Perhaps you can install a certain browser to only the senior's laptops and then parse the user agent with a Perl script, at which point if it succeeds, it will then forward the SVN request.  That's a crappy solution though.  Perhaps you can look into client side scripting solutions and find something that can determine the computer model.

Are the laptops and desktops Windows or Linux or what?